# ¿Por qué node/express muestra UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] cuando registro un usuario?

Tags: nodejs, express

Desde `node/express` hago el registro (signup) de usuario, los datos se guardan en la base de datos, pero  muestra este error:

**(node:9816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[1]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:547:11)
[1]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\cds-bookstore-new\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[1]     at ServerResponse.send (C:\cds-bookstore-new\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[1]     at ServerResponse.json (C:\cds-bookstore-new\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[1]     at C:\cds-bookstore-new\server\dist\controllers\auth.controller.js:31:16
[1]     at Generator.next ()
[1]     at fulfilled (C:\cds-bookstore-new\server\dist\controllers\auth.controller.js:5:58)
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[1] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] (node:9816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

[1] (node:9816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**

aca mi archivo `auth.controller.ts`

```js
export const signup = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    if (!req.body.password || !req.body.registrationdDate || !req.body.email || !req.body.username) {
        res.status(400).send('FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO');
    }
    //recibo los datos (de un form, insomnia rest, etc..)
    const { password, registrationDate, email, username } = (req.body);
    console.log(password, registrationDate, email, username);
    // el id_user es autonumerico en la db lo crea automaticamente
    let pass = password;

    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(pass, 10); // encripta el password 
    // insert en PostgreSQL
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO users (pass, registration_date, email, username) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id_user', [hash, registrationDate, email, username])
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'El usuario fue insertado en la db exitosamente' });
            const idUser = JSON.stringify(data.rows[0].id_user);
            console.log('El id de usuario insertado recientemente es: ' + idUser);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Error no se pudo insertar al usuario en la base de datos ' + error });
        });

};
```

aca `auth.routes.ts`

```js
router.post('api/auth/signup/user', signup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, en esta línea de aquí:

```
    if (!req.body.password || !req.body.registrationdDate || !req.body.email || !req.body.username) {
        res.status(400).send('FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO');
    }
```

Estás enviando una response con un 400. Pero no estás saliendo de la función, eso hace que el código se siga ejecutando y me imagino que la inserción funciona o falla y al intentar enviar el header con un 200 o 400 te da dicho error.

Hace tiempo que no toco node pero diría que la solución es:

```
    if (!req.body.password || !req.body.registrationdDate || !req.body.email || !req.body.username) {
        res.status(400).send('FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO');
        return
    }
```

Por otro lado en el `catch` haces un return que no hace falta.

Por último, el error se refiere a que una vez enviado un body no se pueden enviar más headers.

Comment: gracias por responder!, pero no funciona. Me muestra  el mensaje " falta contenido en el cuerpo". Verfique si los datos llegan, y llegan bien.

Comment: al principio de mi codigo verifico que los datos lleguen bien de esta forma: const { password, registrationDate, email, username } = (req.body);
console.log(password, registrationDate, email, username);

Comment: El error que tenías es porque, por el motivo que sea, te entra en el primer if... ahora es cuestión de averiguar porque te entra en ese if. Seguro que si pones un console.log dentro del if están todos los datos? A ese console.log nunca deberías llegar si te está entrando en el if.. de ahí la necesidad del return.

Comment: pista: `registrationdDate` vs `registrationDate`. pista `dD`

Comment: gracias nax! increible, nunca me dí cuenta de que tenia un "d" de mas muchas gracias! ahora si funciona!

Comment: de nada! a todos nos pasa. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como válida :)